# Minimum cost path in matrix using recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Question -

Given a m x n matrix filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimises the sum of all numbers along its path.

Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

int min_cost(int arr[][2], int start_x, int start_y, int end_x, int end_y)
{
    if(start_x > end_x || start_y > end_y)
      return INT_MAX;

    if( start_x == end_x && start_y == end_y)
      return arr[end_x][end_y];

    int bottom = arr[start_x][start_y] + min_cost(arr, start_x + 1, start_y, end_x, end_y); // Line 1
    int right = arr[start_x][start_y] + min_cost( arr, start_x, start_y + 1, end_x, end_y);  // Line 2

    return min( bottom, right);   // Line 3 
}
int main()
{
    int arr[2][2] = { {1,2},
                      {1,1},
                    };
    cout <<"Min cost is " <<  min_cost(arr, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 Min cost is -2147483647
```

Expected output

```
Min cost is 3
```

If I use below code instead of Line 1, 2 and 3 from the main program then answer is correct.

```
return arr[start_x][start_y] + min( min_cost(arr, start_x + 1, start_y, end_x, end_y), 
                                    min_cost( arr, start_x, start_y + 1, end_x, end_y));
```

Why this is happening ? Are not both codes same ? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: They're not equivalent. If you move `arr[start_x][start_y] + ` *off* the computation of both `bottom` and `right`, and *add* it to the `return` calculation, *then* they're equivalent. You're experiencing signed integer overflow with your first code, which invokes UB. In at least one case your first code triggers an `INT_MAX` return, which is then added to `arr[start_x][start_y]` and stored in `bottom` (or `right`). That addition is what is triggering the overflow, since an `int` can't be bigger than `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 2):

If you write down the recursive calls that are executed during your first solution, you will see that the invalid answer (-2147483647) emerges from adding the last element of the matrix (1) to INT_MAX, which is the value returned by your first recursion exit case.

Below, `min_cost(x, y)[z]` denotes the call of `min_cost` with `start_x=x, start_y=y`, `z` being the index of this recursive call (first call, second call etc.)

```
min_cost(0, 0)[0] -> min(1 + min_cost(1, 0)[1], 1 + min_cost(0, 1)[2])

min_cost(1, 0)[1] -> min(1 + min_cost(2, 0)[3], 1 + min_cost(1, 1)[4])
min_cost(2, 0)[3] -> INT_MAX
min_cost(1, 1)[4] -> 1
```

The last two calls will make call indexed [1] to return `min(1+INT_MAX, 1+1)`, which will be `1+INT_MAX`, which is actually `INT_MIN`, because of integer overflow.

At this point, the first recursive branch of the call indexed [0] is computed, so `min_cost(0, 0)[0]` will have to choose between `1+INT_MIN` and the second branch result (which we did not unroll here). `1+INT_MIN` will be at least as small as the result of the second branch, so this is what your first algorithm returns - `1+INT_MIN`.

Your second version of the algorithm produces the correct result, since the result of the recursive call that previously returned `INT_MAX` will now get compared against the second result, in this line: `min(min_cost(...), min_cost(...))`.
If it is first compared against a value smaller than it, then `min` will return the smaller value and only after that add it to the value in the current matrix cell (instead of first adding it with the value in the current cell, producing an overflow an passing over the wrong result).